# Copying a virtual file to the clipboard

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard, ole

By slightly modifying the code from the [Raymond Chen's article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080318-00/?p=23083), I got a class for copying a vector to the clipboard as a file:

```
typedef std::wstring String;

class CFileDataObject : public IDataObject
{
public:
  // IUnknown
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
    {
        IUnknown *punk = NULL;
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
            punk = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
        else if (riid == IID_IDataObject)
        {
        punk = static_cast<IDataObject*>(this);
        }
        *ppv = punk;
        if (punk)
        {
            punk->AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        else return E_NOINTERFACE;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        return ++m_cRef;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        ULONG cRef = --m_cRef;
        if (cRef == 0)
        {
            delete this;
        }
        return cRef;
    }
    // IDataObject
    STDMETHODIMP GetData(FORMATETC *pfe, STGMEDIUM *pmed)
    {
        ZeroMemory(pmed, sizeof(*pmed));
        switch (GetDataIndex(pfe))
        {
        case DATA_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR:
            {
            FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR fgd;
            ZeroMemory(&fgd, sizeof(fgd));
            fgd.cItems = 1;
            fgd.fgd[0].dwFlags = FD_FILESIZE | FD_WRITESTIME;
            fgd.fgd[0].nFileSizeLow = DataSize & 0xFFFFFFFFULL;
            fgd.fgd[0].nFileSizeHigh = (DataSize & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ULL) >> 32;
            fgd.fgd[0].ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime = 0x256d4000;
            fgd.fgd[0].ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime = 0x01bf53eb; 
            StringCchCopy(fgd.fgd[0].cFileName,ARRAYSIZE(fgd.fgd[0].cFileName),
                m_FileName.c_str());
            pmed->tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
            return CreateHGlobalFromBlob(&fgd, sizeof(fgd),GMEM_MOVEABLE, &pmed->hGlobal);
            }
        case DATA_FILECONTENTS:
            pmed->tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
            pmed->hGlobal = hData;
            return S_OK;
        }
        return DV_E_FORMATETC;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP GetDataHere(FORMATETC *pfe, STGMEDIUM *pmed)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP QueryGetData(FORMATETC *pfe)
    {
        return GetDataIndex(pfe) == DATA_INVALID ? S_FALSE : S_OK;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP GetCanonicalFormatEtc(FORMATETC *pfeIn,FORMATETC *pfeOut)
    {
        *pfeOut = *pfeIn;
        pfeOut->ptd = NULL;
        return DATA_S_SAMEFORMATETC;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP SetData(FORMATETC *pfe, STGMEDIUM *pmed,BOOL fRelease)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP EnumFormatEtc(DWORD dwDirection,LPENUMFORMATETC *ppefe)
    {
        if (dwDirection == DATADIR_GET)
            return SHCreateStdEnumFmtEtc(ARRAYSIZE(m_rgfe), m_rgfe, ppefe);
        *ppefe = NULL;
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP DAdvise(FORMATETC *pfe, DWORD grfAdv,IAdviseSink *pAdvSink, DWORD *pdwConnection)
    {
        return OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP DUnadvise(DWORD dwConnection)
    {
        return OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED;
    };
    STDMETHODIMP EnumDAdvise(LPENUMSTATDATA *ppefe)
    {
        return OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED;
    };

    CFileDataObject(const String& FileName, const std::vector<uint8_t>& Data)
        : m_cRef(1),m_FileName(FileName)
    {
        SetFORMATETC(&m_rgfe[DATA_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR],
            RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR));
        SetFORMATETC(&m_rgfe[DATA_FILECONTENTS],
            RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS),TYMED_HGLOBAL, 0);
        HRESULT hres = CreateHGlobalFromBlob(Data.data(), Data.size(), GMEM_MOVEABLE, &hData);
        if (!SUCCEEDED(hres)) { /* Some error handling goes here */ };
        DataSize = Data.size();
    }
private:
    enum {
        DATA_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR,
        DATA_FILECONTENTS,
        DATA_NUM,
        DATA_INVALID = -1,
    };
int GetDataIndex(const FORMATETC *pfe)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(m_rgfe); i++)
    {
        if (pfe->cfFormat == m_rgfe[i].cfFormat && (pfe->tymed & m_rgfe[i].tymed) &&
            pfe->dwAspect == m_rgfe[i].dwAspect && pfe->lindex   == m_rgfe[i].lindex)
                return i;
    }
    return DATA_INVALID;
}
private:
    ULONG m_cRef;
    FORMATETC m_rgfe[DATA_NUM];
    String m_FileName;
    HGLOBAL hData = 0;
    size_t DataSize = 0;
};
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> FileData;
    // Filling the vector with some data
IDataObject* fdo = new CFileDataObject(FileName, FileData);
if (fdo)
{
    HRESULT hres = OleSetClipboard(fdo);
    fdo->Release();
}
```

The class serves its purpose, but there is one detail: the file can only be pasted only once. All further attempts to paste the file fail. Is this normal or is there something wrong with the class?

Comment: Side note: I am pretty sure you have to call `OleFlushClipboard` after you call `OleSetClipboard`. That keeps the data alive after your application closes. Also, if I didn't flush, I would get memory leaks, if I remember correctly. I could have implemented it all wrong though :)

Comment: You don't have to implement your own IDataObject from scratch. Use SHCreateDataObject https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shcreatedataobject like this: `SHCreateDataObject(nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr, IID_IDataObject, &dataObj)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GetData()` is returning the original `hData` object for `DATA_FILECONTENTS` instead of a copy. Since the `pmed->pUnkForRelease` field is being returned as NULL, the caller of `GetData()` will free the returned `HGLOBAL` when done using it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ns-objidl-ustgmedium-r1

> `pUnkForRelease`
>
> Pointer to an interface instance that allows the sending process to control the way the storage is released when the receiving process calls the `ReleaseStgMedium` function. **If `pUnkForRelease` is NULL, `ReleaseStgMedium` uses default procedures to release the storage**; otherwise, `ReleaseStgMedium` uses the specified `IUnknown` interface.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ole2/nf-ole2-releasestgmedium

> **The provider indicates that the receiver of the medium is responsible for freeing the medium by specifying NULL for the `punkForRelease` structure member.** Then the receiver calls `ReleaseStgMedium`, which makes a call as described in the following table depending on the type of storage medium being freed.
>
> | Medium | ReleaseStgMedium Action |
> | --- | --- |
> | TYMED_HGLOBAL | Calls the `GlobalFree` function on the handle. |

So, to keep that from happening, set `pmed->pUnkForRelease` to an AddRef'ed `IUnknown` that is responsible for freeing `hData` when noone is using it anymore. In your case, you can use the `this` pointer for your `CFileDataObject` object for that `IUnknown` interface.

> When the original provider of the medium is responsible for freeing the medium, the provider calls `ReleaseStgMedium`, specifying the medium and the appropriate `IUnknown` pointer as the `punkForRelease` structure member. Depending on the type of storage medium being freed, one of the following actions is taken, **followed by a call to the `IUnknown::Release` method on the specified `IUnknown`  pointer**.
>
> | Medium | ReleaseStgMedium Action |
> | --- | --- |
> | TYMED_HGLOBAL | None. |

Otherwise, another option is to implement `DATA_FILECONTENTS` as an `IStream` instead of an `HGLOBAL`, where the `IStream` accesses the original `vector` data. This option is even described in the [Shell Clipboard Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#cfstr_filecontents) documentation:

> CFSTR_FILECONTENTS
>
> This format identifier is used with the `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` format to transfer data as if it were a file, regardless of how it is actually stored. The data consists of an `STGMEDIUM` structure that represents the contents of one file. **The file is normally represented as a stream object, which avoids having to place the contents of the file in memory.** In that case, the tymed member of the `STGMEDIUM` structure is set to `TYMED_ISTREAM`, and the file is represented by an `IStream` interface. The file can also be a storage or global memory object (`TYMED_ISTORAGE` or `TYMED_HGLOBAL`). The associated `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` format contains a `FILEDESCRIPTOR` structure for each file that specifies the file's name and attributes.

Comment: It looks like you can't return the same `HGLOBAL` every time. Starting from the second paste I get a segmentation fault.  I now store the vector in the class and re-create the `HGLOBAL` every time, and this works. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: "*It looks like you can't return the same HGLOBAL every time*" - You should be able to, as long as the caller doesn't free it. Provide a non-null `pUnkForRelease`. The caller *should* be using `ReleaseStgMedium()`, not freeing the contents of the `STGMEDIUM` manually. "*I now store the vector in the class and re-create the HGLOBAL every time*" - yes, that will work. Though, now that you have taken that step, it would be trivial to return an `IStream` that reads from the `vector`'s data directly (see `SHCreateMemStream()`), instead of returning an `HGLOBAL` that is a copy of the vector's data.

Comment: I provided `this` in `pUnkForRelease`. It does not work after the first paste and that's it :) I don't know why. I tried pasting with explorer, it still doesn't work after the first time, so the problem is not in the caller, I think.

Comment: Did you remember to call `AddRef()` before returning? You can use `QueryInterface()` to handle that, eg: `pmed->tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL; pmed->hGlobal = hData; this->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void**)&pmed->pUnkForRelease); return S_OK;` Otherwise handle it explicitly: `pmed->tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL; pmed->hGlobal = hData; pmed->pUnkForRelease = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this); this->AddRef(); return S_OK;` I still recommend going the `IStream` approach, though. It is just more memory-efficient.